# Conditional T distribution

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

Suppose $(X,Y)$ has a bivariate t distribution. I want to plot the density of the conditional density of $Y$ given $X$, i.e. $Y|X$. I wonder why the following does not work:

```
bivT = MultivariateTDistribution[{{1, ρ}, { ρ, 1}}, ν]
bivTCond[x_, y_, ν_, ρ_]:= 
    Evaluate@PDF[bivT, {x, y, ν, ρ}] /
      Evaluate@PDF[StudentTDistribution[0, 1, ν], {x, ν}]
Plot[bivTCond[1, y, 3, 0.5], {y, -3, 3}]
```

The last command does not produce any plot.

Comment: Note that `Evaluate[PDF[...]]/Evaluate[PDF[...]]` doesn't really do anything, since `Evaluate` is only special when it's at the first level (which is `/` in this case.)  Perhaps you meant to use `Evaluate[PDF[...]/PDF[...]]`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
bivTCond[x_, y_, ν_, ρ_] := 
 Evaluate @ PDF[MultivariateTDistribution[{{1, ρ}, {ρ, 1}}, ν], {x, y}]/
 Evaluate @ PDF[StudentTDistribution[0, 1, ν], x]

Plot[bivTCond[1, y, 3, 0.5], {y, -3, 3}]
```

[image: PDF of conditional t distribution]

Comment: Mathematica markup is hard to read, so until the [syntax highlighter](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/118/52) is installed on this site, I'd suggest refraining from using it whenever possible. As such, I've transformed your variables from `\[Nu]` to `Nu` and the like.

Comment: Good suggestion. I'll do that in the future as well.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Do you mind to explain why my function was not working. It would help me to understand how Mathematica works.

Comment: Well, one error in your function is that you were passing {x,y,nu,rho} to the PDF, but the final argument to the PDF should only be the two random variables, not the statistical parameters. The same holds for the second distribution.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. Here is another version which still gives me error.

Comment: bivT[\[Nu]_, \[Rho]_] := 
 MultivariateTDistribution[{{1, \[Rho]}, {\[Rho], 1}}, \[Nu]]
bivTCond[x_, y_, \[Nu]_, \[Rho]_] := 
 Evaluate@PDF[bivT, {x, y}]/
  Evaluate@PDF[StudentTDistribution[0, 1, \[Nu]], {x}]
Plot[bivTCond[1, y, 3, 0.5], {y, -3, 3}]

Answer (score 8):

**Here's a tutorial on how to debug such things**

The first thing you must try when this happens is you should put a number in place of `y` and see what the expression evaluates to:

```
bivTCond[1, 1, 3, 0.5]

(*
==> {(
 8 Pi PDF[
   MultivariateTDistribution[{{1, rho}, {rho, 1}}, nu], {1, 1, 3, 
    0.5}])/(3 Sqrt[3]), 
 8 Sqrt[3] Pi PDF[
   MultivariateTDistribution[{{1, rho}, {rho, 1}}, nu], {1, 1, 3, 
    0.5}]}
*)
```

You can see that there are still free variables present (`rho` and `nu`).  This is not a numerical quantity, so obviously it can't be used in a plot.

To understand why `rho` and `nu` were not properly substituted by numbers, read about [`:=` vs `=`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ImmediateAndDelayedDefinitions.html).  The first fix needed is using `=` instead of `:=` in the definition of `bivTCond`.  The `Evaluate` function is superfluous here, so I'll remove that one too:

```
bivT = MultivariateTDistribution[{{1, rho}, {rho, 1}}, nu]
bivTCond[x_, y_, nu_, rho_] = 
 PDF[bivT, {x, y, nu, rho}] / PDF[StudentTDistribution[0, 1, nu], {x, nu}]
```

Out test experssion still won't evaluate to a numerical quantity though:

```
bivTCond[1, 1, 3, 0.5]

(*
==> {(
 8 Pi PDF[
   MultivariateTDistribution[{{1, 0.5}, {0.5, 1}}, 3], {1, 1, 3, 
    0.5}])/(3 Sqrt[3]), 
 8 Sqrt[3] Pi PDF[
   MultivariateTDistribution[{{1, 0.5}, {0.5, 1}}, 3], {1, 1, 3, 
    0.5}]}
*)
```

The reason for this is that `PDF` was used with the wrong syntax.  Check any of the examples on the doc page of [`MultivariateTDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MultivariateTDistribution.html) to see how to use it: the parameters should not be included in the second argument of `PDF`

Let's fix this too:

```
bivT = MultivariateTDistribution[{{1, rho}, {rho, 1}}, nu]
bivTCond[x_, y_, nu_, rho_] = 
 PDF[bivT, {x, y}]/PDF[StudentTDistribution[0, 1, nu], {x, nu}]
```

And now it works:

```
Plot[bivTCond[1, y, 3, 0.5], {y, -3, 3}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The morale here is:  build up your expressions *step by step*, checking that they work at each stage!  Then you'll catch mistakes early.  This is how all of us work, and how we debug these problems.

Comment: Many thanks indeed for a very helpful reply.

Comment: @Mikael You should verify if you really wanted two number in `PDF[StudentTDistribution[...], {x,nu}]` though (I mean `{x,nu}`) ...

Comment: Sure, I noticed that and realized that should remove nu. Thanks again.

Comment: +1. Very good advice. I would just add something on localization of variables when using `Set` (or at least some `ClearAll` call on those symbols prior to `Set`), so that people won't start blindly using `Set` and get funny results.